# Is it possible to associate file extensions without a special permission from Microsoft?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

If no, are there any alternative solutions to mimic the given behavior ? I've developed a "parser" of sorts for a custom file format and would like to be able to open such a file on my WP Mango.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this "feature" isn't available without explicit permission from Microsoft. And no, there are no real alternative solutions.

Comment: Sad, confused and left wondering, why Microsoft would block such a common piece of functionality for its developers. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: I'm not in a position to comment on that. But you can always suggest it on the [UserVoice site](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions), if it's not already there.

Comment: I'd be surprised if such a thing exists in the first place.